# Grab the value of latest textbox on a particular variable having multiple textbox with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the value of last textbox to be grabbed by the varialble on multiple textbox with same ID.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="get"><br>
<input type="text" id="get"><br>
    <button id="grab">Click</button><br>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#grab").click(function(){
   var value = $("#get").val(); 
});
```

Or, a way to delete the first textbox might also work.
 [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/orghoLzg/)

Comment: HTML elements can't have the same `id` attribute. Use the `class` attribute, instead.

Comment: What's with the closevote? The problem here isn't a typo, and _can_ be reproduced.

Comment: Since multiple elements can't have the same `id`, your HTML is invalid.  Any JavaScript behavior on invalid HTML is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid: HTML elements can't have the same `id` attribute.
Use the `class` attribute, instead.

You can then use [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) to get the last element that matches the `.get` selector:

```js
$("#grab").click(function(){
  var value = $(".get").last().val(); 
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="get" value="foo"><br>
<input type="text" class="get" value="bar"><br>
<button id="grab">Click</button><br>
```

<sub>(I added the `value` attributes for demonstrative purposes. Obviously, they can be removed.)</sub>

---

If you want to get the first element's value if the second one is empty, you could do this:

```
$("#grab").click(function(){
    var firstValue = $(".get").val(); // `.val()` gets the first element's value by default
    var secondValue = $(".get").last().val(); 

    var result = secondValue || firstValue;
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way that it would grab the first value if the second value is empty.

Comment: This is showing the value of last textbox, i want it to show the updated value among the textbox if possible.

Comment: You can get the first value if the second is empty. I added a bit to my answer to do that.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't have any control on `id`s you should use following solution. If you can change the ids you should change them.

You approach will not work because the `id` is not unique. It will always get the first `input`.

```
$("#grab").click(function() {
    // var value = $(this).prev("input").val(); // Will work when there is no `<br>`
    alert($('input[id="get"]').last().val());
});
```

Here `$('input[id="get"]')` will get all the elements having id `get` and `last()` will get the last element from it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/orghoLzg/1/

Comment: This answer doesn't mention the real problem in the OP (Non-unique ID's), nor does it explain why it supposedly works.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's what OP wants.

Comment: What the OP wants isn't always possible, or a good idea. Quite often, exactly what the OP wants is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: `If you don't have any control on ids you should use following solution. If you can change the ids you should change them.` +1 this happens sometimes, when you are having CMS or third party plugins

Comment: A CMS or plugin should be clever enough not to duplicate ID's.